# How to make select2 results look like "Tag + 3 more options selected"?

Tags: jquery-select2

I've been asked to change select2 widget default behavior. Instead of showing multiple selected items stacked like it does by default:

```
* Alaska
* Hawaii
* California
* Nevada
```

to re-configure in to input showing

```
* Alaska + 3 more items selected.
```

The whole point of the idea is to keep the input always of the same height.

I'm not even sure where to start. I've read the documentation, couldn't find anything helpful in API. Though it is sparse. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.